# How to attach source code to iOS static library?

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I'm working on the iOS SDK. Which is to be distributed as a static library + header files. Or like a static iOS framework.

My question is - can I attach the source code to this library?
Like it's done in Java - jar file with source code inside.

So the developers can view and debug source code inside. But can't change it.

Thanks

Comment: Well you can, I guess, however it's very unusual.  You may just as well provide the source + Xcode project and a separate pre-built library, rather than mixing the two.

Comment: I have an unusual project) Do you have any idea how? Would appreciate)

Comment: Zip up the source files, I guess.